# Why is $mail->send() in phpMailer called twice in a row?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have problem while sending mail, my user gets 2 identical mails, I tried to find a solution but no one. Please help me!

```
class SendMail
{
    private $mail;
    private $subject;
    private $body;
    private $receiver;

    public function __construct($subject, $body, $receiver)
    {
        $this->mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->body = $body;
        $this->receiver = $receiver;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $a = rand(1, 100);
//           SMTP Setting
            $this->mail->isSMTP();
            $this->mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $this->mail->Username = '';
            $this->mail->Password = '';
            $this->mail->Port = 465;
            $this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
            $this->mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
            $this->mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

//          Email Setting
            $this->mail->setFrom('', '');
            $this->mail->addAddress($this->receiver);
            $this->mail->Subject = $this->subject.$a;
            $this->mail->Body = $this->body;
            $this->mail->AltBody = $this->body;
            $this->mail->addReplyTo('');
            $this->mail->send();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

I used the rand function to test if the correct mail was sent twice and it is.

I call it in the Controller every time the method is called

```
class HomeController
{
    public function test(){
        $mail = new SendMail('', '', '');
        $mail->handle();
        require Helpers::View('user', 'detail_tour');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post more code of the context that calls it? this is not enough

Comment: @mfadel I am testing it, so I call it every time the website loads

Comment: This can happen for a number of reasons. The most common I see in such problems is the browser making several requests. For example a preflight request for CORS, etc. Check the network tab in the browser dev tools to see which requests are made and do some logging on the server side for each request

Comment: can you post more code of the file that contains those lines of codes?
$mail = new SendMail('aaa', 'aaa', 'myemail');
        $mail->handle();

Comment: @KhảNam can you post the entire code where the $mail->handle() was present ?

Comment: @Inazo i was update post

Comment: It's possible your code run two times the HomeController->test() ?

Comment: Good call trying the random number trick; I've recommended that in the past. There is [a PHPMailer wiki article on diagnosing repeat emails](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Diagnosing-email-sending-twice-(or-more)). The most common explanation I've found is from browser plugins that do repeat posts, so try in a new browser, or in incognito mode with plugins disabled.